# Software Development Methodologies with Example Projects

Tags: methodology

There are a lot of information about Software Development Methodologies (Waterfall, Prototyping, Iterative, Incremental, Spiral etc.). On the other hand, generally information is about how phases are scheduled and what should be done in particular phases.

I want to see real life examples of Software Development Methodologies. How did people implement these methodologies on their particular projects, what were the problems, how did they cope with them, etc. ?

Do you know any resources where I can find example projects with given software development methodology?

**List of what I have found:**

- [Agile Specification](http://www.agilespec.com/)
- [Shell Method](http://www.shellmethod.com/)

Comment: 1 - community wiki 2 - belongs on programmers, not here

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about a well known resource with collected case studies, but short [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=case+study+scrum) for *scrum case studies* point to this [link](http://agilepainrelief.com/notesfromatooluser/2008/11/scrum-case-studies.html).

Myself I've read most experience reports in magazines, not only for software developers but for project management or controller but this is not what you are asking for.